# Deploying Angula2 UI application in High Availability Mode

Tags: angular

Currently we have implemented a Angular2 UI application and deployed in single server. We would like to implement the UI application in high availability mode by deploying the UI application in 2 servers(1 in active mode and another one in stand-by mode).  Is there any easy way of implementing it in Angular2 and nodeJS?

Thanks,
Rajkumar

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 runs in the client (browser) only.

The server only serves static HTML, JS, and CSS files. There are no specific requirements for an Angular2 server (except when you want to use server side rendering). Just build your Angular2 source and you will only get static files for deployment.

Any HTTP server will do and any HTTP server can serve multiple clients (it's main purpose ;-)  )